# Python equivalent of the Stata command iebaltab

Tags: python, stata

I need to do a simple balance table between two groups in Python. In Stata, I'd use the command iebaltab, but I couldn't find something similar. Do you know a package that does it?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: My guess is that you need to write this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This package produces tables of descriptive statistics in Python, which are sometimes referred to as the "Table 1" of a paper.

https://pypi.org/project/tableone/

As a side note, the Stata package `table1` has similar functionality to the `iebaltab` package you referenced.